# Cannot install smtplib,help will be appreciated

Tags: python-3.x

```
Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install secure-smtplib
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install secure-smtplib
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>>
```

Comment: `pip` is a shell command, not a Python command. You run it outside the Python interpreter.

Comment: That said, you can't install `secure-smtplib` in Python 3 anyway (it's meant for Python 2), and `smtplib` is a standard library module, so there's nothing to install.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't install [`secure-smtplib`](https://pypi.org/project/secure-smtplib) on Python 3; it's meant for Python 2.
2. [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) is a standard library module, so there is nothing to install if you just want to use `smtplib`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  2 2023, 20:46:14) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import smtplib
<module 'smtplib' from 'Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py'>
```

Comment: well, thanks again